# What is The Meaning Of Array<number>()?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

```
let a = Array<number>();
console.log(a);
```

Does It Means something like

```
let a = new Array();
```

Comment: it means the items inside the array is a number and it should be a number

Comment: `let a = Array<number>();` in TypeScript is actually equivalent to `let a = Array()` in JavaScript. There's no need to use the `new` operator in this specific case as the results are the same due to how the `Array` constructor function works, but this does not apply to constructor functions in general.

Answer (score 8):

What comes between the `<>` are *type arguments*, used to tell TypeScript a type associated with the call. Functions that take type arguments are called [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) - see that page for an extended description of them.

Passing `number` as a type argument with `Array<number>` indicates to TypeScript that the array will be composed of numbers. That is, you'll be permitted to do:

```
a.push(10);
```

later, but you won't be permitted to do

```
a.push('somestring');
```

If you don't give it a type argument, it'll be typed as `Array<any>`, permitting *any values* to be used, which loses type-safety and usually isn't what you want.

Note that with Arrays, one should usually avoid the Array constructor and instead just use an empty array literal:

```
const a: Array<number> = [];
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to create an empty array in Javascript:

```
let a = new Array();
```

But this way you **type** your array in typescript:

```
Array<number>
```

You can combine them and create an empty array of numbers:

```
const arr: Array<number> = new Array();
// or simply
const arr: number[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

it means that you will store only numbers inside the array if you have already ever worked with other programming language like java you will notice the difference between java and javaScript on there you should use array like this
int[] myArray = new int[5];
this mean that the value that you are going to store inside this array will be in type integer and if you try to store any String or other data type you won't allowed, and in javaScript since the data type is not clear at the time when we declare an array we can use <dataType> for consistency and to to be sure what we are goin to store inside array